# Does it make sense to use a non-relational database for reporting/BI/visualisation tools?

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, nosql, reporting

Relational databases are well used in **reporting/visualisation tools** such as Power BI, Tableau...

Non-relational databases are getting popular and many reporting tools allow its connection. However I do not believe it is a **best practice** to use non-relational databases for projects whose objective is business reporting or visualization with tools such as Tableau and Power BI (or other business inteligence tools) because most BI reporting tools base their logic on tabular data.
It is true that tools like Power BI and Tableau offer workarounds to import non-tabular data, i.e transforming it during the import. But I do not believe workarounds are "best practices". They are just ways to do it for edge cases. Best practice is for me, something stable, flexible, used by most of the companies and well-known approach

Could someone counter-argument my statement ?

Is it realistic, simple and **recommended** to use non-relational databases for business reporting ?

Comment: "However I do not believe it is a best practice to use non-relational databases for projects whose objective is business reporting or visualization with tools such as Tableau and Power BI (or other business inteligence tools)" - please define _best practices_ and how you came to this opinion...

Comment: ...or rather: why do you think non-relational ("NoSQL"?) databases are inappropriate for reporting?

Comment: @Dai Thanks Dai. I edited and replied to your comments directly in the description. I don't get why my post has negative points :( What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-relational databases when you have a use case that can't as easily be accomplished in a relational one *or* if it's your own preference to use one. They both are equally able to accomplish many similar goals and most times when to use one is subjective.

> Is it realistic, simple and **recommended** to use non-relational databases for business reporting ?

Sure, it can be, depending on the reporting needs of the consumers. Non-relational databases can be used equivalently to denormalized tables in relational database systems. Denormalized tables are not uncommon in a data warehouse in a relational database system, especially for pre-calculated fields, such as aggregations.

A table in a non-relational database system may emulate the same use cases as a view that combines multiple tables back together in a relational database. A view may be used for reporting and / or BI. There's no limits against doing so.

Yes, tools like PowerBI *can* offer flexibility to the user by building out star schema-like data models inside the tool itself. Doing so with the base database objects of a relational database system may be more conductive to that specific facet of BI, but that isn't what is always best or needed for the end users using BI either. Rather that's just one possible way to architect your BI schema. And it's technically still possible to design a *related* data model of your non-relational tables inside PowerBI, depending on how your non-relational model is architected.

So it really just depends on your use cases. There is no "*best practice*" regarding this.

Comment: "A table in a non-relational database system may emulate the same use cases as a view that combines multiple tables back together in a relational database" - that's a contradiction though: a "table" **is** a _relation_: any database system that uses a set-_relations_ (i.e. "tables") to represent data **is** a "relational database". The term "relation" has nothing to do with FK constraints (aka "relationship") - and plenty of NoSQL databases do support some kind of FK constraint, but strictly speaking that's orthogonal to whether a DBMS is an RDBMS or not.

Comment: "a view that combines multiple tables back together in a relational database" - A `VIEW` is limited to combining relations using only `INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOIN` - or through set-operations on homogenous relations (`UNION`, `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT`, etc) - whereas invariably the "best" (imo) way to represent and transfer a typical RDBMS object-graph is through entirely separate result-sets for each object class (i.e. separate `SELECT` statements, often without the need for any `JOIN` or `UNION` at all) - but there's still an annoying lack of tooling support for multiple result-set queries - argh

Comment: @Dai Mate, I'm not sure what you're on about, but nothing you stated seems to be related to my post. This question / my answer has nothing to do with relations, foreign keys, limitations of operators in views, etc. In the context of the question, which is the context of BI, my point regarding a view is that one might denormalize their relational database schema into a view to make consumption in BI easier for the end user, and the shape of that structure may emulate the shape of a similar denormalized NoSQL table, which could serve the same purpose, as an example how NoSQL is valid in BI.

Comment: Usually many companies needs relational, joinable, consistent and normalised data, that's why I consider to be a best practice to use relational databases for reporting. First, and the foremost important point is joinability. Relational databases are made for that. Usually companies need to join different data sources and entities. Sure non-relational can work but for some use cases but as a general rule I do not see it working for most companies that have entities such as "customer", "sales"... in different objects/tables

Comment: @greenglas My preference is a RDBMS, which is why I said "*You should use non-relational databases when you have a use case that can't as easily be accomplished in a relational one or if it's your own preference to use one.*". For traditional data models and use cases, most times a RDBMS will be sufficient but there are companies out there with *common* entity types such as `customer` and `sales` who still need or prefer to use a NoSQL solution because of either the high rate the model changes in structure or because the model structure is defined by an outside source & is out of their hands.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking about [BI/OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). Although "reporting" in your title might merely be talking about transactional reporting/audit trails/exceptions/etc.

> Relational databases are well used in reporting/visualisation tools such as Power BI, Tableau...

False. There might be SQL or relational tables at the 'front' of an analytics engine as staging/data-scrubbing.

But for the heavy duty part of an analytics engine, the data is held in 'star schemas' and 'cubes' -- which are de-normalised and pre-calculated with aggregates. Deliberately very much not relational. [Links to those terms of art from within the OLAP article.]

> Non-relational databases ...

I assume by "non-relational" you mean 'NoSQL'. (There would be many who say SQL is non-Relational.)

No, NoSQL databases are not the right tool for intensive data analytics -- for the same reason SQL databases are not the right tool.

Comment: "No, NoSQL databases are not the right tool for intensive data analytics -- for the same reason SQL databases are not the right tool." Then what ? :) I do not like to use the term SQL Databases because SQL is a subset of NoSQL.

Comment: "Then what ?" That OLAP link I provided includes a section on 'Products'. That's by no means comprehensive, neither am I endorsing any particular product: I do not know what are your business requirements. And no SQL is _not_ a "subset" of NoSQL. Not even wrong.

Comment: when you say 'front' of an analytics engine are you referring for example that Power BI allows to join data and create tables in the engine itself? What I am trying to avoid are workarounds or less-used solutions. Yes, at the end everything is possible. I am rather referring to what most companies actually implement (on average)

Comment: You need to choose a product then take training from the vendor for their particular approach. StackOverflow is not a training forum for "what most companies actually implement".

Answer (score -1):

I am currently a report writer for cognos bi. And I can definitely say it is not safe to force relational data to relational in most cases. I am currently being forced to write a report pulling fields that have no relation to the main records. It can become a situational report which is never good for a BI report. It may work for now but later down the road another situation may pose a problem when data is entered incorrectly. Just makes it very frustrating for the report writer to work around non relational data.